# <a> Trying to set up basic link

Tags: html, anchor

html beginner here. Just trying to set up a basic link. When I click my link, this is the address it takes me to, instead of just the google homepage. Anyone know why it includes users/name/desktop in front?

webpagefile:///Users/jeffreygers/Desktop/“http://google.com”

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Example Title Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href=“http://google.com”>Link</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to include some more code for us to know what's wrong but you might be able to figure this out on your own at various sources. E.g. http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please provide your code so we can see what's wrong on it

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Click Here</a>
```

Use the above line in your code. For me, it helped

Comment: The difference is in the quotes

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.